# Convert Metric Kilotons to Metric Tons before save data in table

Tags: c#, oracle

### I WANT TO CONVERT 'CAPACITY' KT into T before save data in table.

Note: If 'CAPACITY' is in KT then it should be convert in T & if it in T then it not need to convert. ( **Metric Tons to Metric Kilotons (t to kt)** 1 Metric Tons = 0.001 metric kilotons  )

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing in this?

Comment: Is there a way to tell the units of measurement, I can't figure it out from your code, once you do, the rest is pretty simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result1 = string.Empty;
            int Count = 0;
            var str = objYardData.CAPACITY;
            var pat = "KT$";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(str, pat))
            {
                var patt1 = "\\d+";

                result1 = Regex.Match(str, patt1).Value;
                Count = (Convert.ToInt32(result1) * 1000);
                result1 = Count .ToString() + " T";
            }
            else
            {
                result1 = objYardData.CAPACITY;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regular expression` to compare the capacity. Try using  regex `match` to find if the string has "KT" at end. If it contain KT strip the digits and convert to float or double. process the data convert to string and attach T.

```
var str = "1000 KT";
var pat=/KT$/g;
if(str.match(pat)){
  var patt1 = /\d+/g;
  var result = str.match(patt1); //this will give 1000 as result

//Convert it to Float,double or int as you need and process.
}
```

**---edit-1----**

If it didn't work try it for `C#`

use `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

and

```
var str = "1000 KT";
var pat="KT$";
if(Regex.IsMatch(str,pat)){
     var patt1 = "\\d+";
     var result = Regex.Match(str,patt1); //this will give 1000 as result

    //Convert it to Float,double or int as you need and process.
}
```

Comment: Ya...Its Working...@Jinto Jacob

Comment: Edit my Solution code in my Above code. ( In Question Section )